# How to resolve ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable

Tags: angular, angular-formbuilder

I have read every other question about this but I didn't get a definite answer.

I have a Reactive Form like so:

```js
this.recipe = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      ingredients: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          amount: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      ]),
      steps: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required)
      ])
    });
```

When I run this and I fill up the form I get an error saying:

```
ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
```

How do I fix this? I have not added any Custom Validators and stuff.

Another fact is that this only happens when I add something new to the FormArray.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. When I add a new FormArray I accidentally added another Validator. Removing it fixed the problem.